# How can I join a second table and enter its contents into a single field of the first table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am just starting out with (Oracle) SQL and am stuck with a problem. Basically I want to transform a table of unknown size into a single field in another table. Actually there are more tables involved but I will try to create a simpler example case. Say there is a table `CUSTOMERS`:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | John Smith |
| 17 | Jane Doe |

And a table `DETAILS`:

| ID | DETAIL | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Street | Elm St. |
| 5 | Post_code | 12345 |
| 5 | Number | 17 |
| 17 | Telephone | 09999999 |
| 17 | Fax | 088888888888 |

So for each customer there may be different information, and without knowing all the possible entries in `DETAILS.DETAIL`, I want to put them into a single field as key-value-pairs like this:

| ID | NAME | DETAILS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | John Smith | Street: Elm St. Post_code: 12345 Number: 17 |
| 17 | Jane Doe | Telephone: 09999999 Fax: 088888888888 |

Roughly, what I can do so far is:

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMERS.ID
    ,CUSTOMERS.NAME
    ,DETAILS.DETAIL || ': ' || DETAILS.VALUE
FROM
    CUSTOMERS
    JOIN DETAILS ON CUSTOMERS.ID = DETAILS.ID
```

But this adds one row for each detail that is known about a customer. My aim is to still retain one row per customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with the following query.

`db<>fiddle` link: https://dbfiddle.uk/k02CrDnU

The below query works on modern versions of Oracle (tested on `18c, 21c, and 23c`):

```
SELECT 
    c.ID, 
    c.NAME,
    LISTAGG(d.DETAIL || ': ' || d.VALUE, ' ') AS DETAILS
FROM 
    CUSTOMERS c
JOIN 
    DETAILS d ON c.ID = d.ID
GROUP BY 
    c.ID, c.NAME;
```

If you're on an older version of Oracle (e.g. `11g release 2`), you'll have to add `WITHIN` statement. The following query is the revised version of the above query that works on old versions too.

```
SELECT 
    c.ID, 
    c.NAME,
    LISTAGG(d.DETAIL || ': ' || d.VALUE, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY d.DETAIL DESC) AS DETAILS
FROM 
    CUSTOMERS c
JOIN 
    DETAILS d ON c.ID = d.ID
GROUP BY 
    c.ID, c.NAME;
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much. I am indeed working with 12c so the WITHIN statement was necessary.

Comment: Awesome! So glad to hear it could help you!

Answer (score 1):

You'll use [`LISTAGG()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) to aggregate the string values of multiple records into a single record grouped by the customer's `id` and `name`, like so:

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMERS.ID
    ,CUSTOMERS.NAME
    ,LISTAGG(DETAILS.DETAIL || ': ' || DETAILS.VALUE, ' ') as DETAILS
FROM
    CUSTOMERS
    JOIN DETAILS ON CUSTOMERS.ID = DETAILS.ID
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.ID, CUSTOMERS.NAME
```